# how to connect Redshift from putty?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I am trying to connect redshift from my local windows putty instance. After creating Redshift instance , it is generated leader and compute node ip address.

Question is

1. which node role i need to pick ? Compute / Leader
2. for those which ip address i need to pick ? private / public
3. How to add public SSH key into my local putty?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot SSH into a Redshift cluster since Redshift is a fully managed data warehouse service. All cluster administration is done by the Redshift service.

To connect to the Redshift database from the command line you use `psql`. This is installed as part of a Postgres installation. Any version of Postgres or `psql` later than 8.0 should work.

Alternatively you can connect using any SQL tool that support JDBC or ODBC.

You would normally connect to the `Endpoint` address but, if needed, you can also connect to the `Leader` node IP address.

```
psql -h my-cluster-name.ahashvalue.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5439 -d mydatabasename -U masteruser
```

Or

```
psql -h 54.nnn.nnn.nnn -p 5439 -d mydatabasename -U masteruser
```

Comment: Thanks @joe Harris .. Why we need ssh key which mentioned redshift cluster page

Comment: It is used when ingesting from EMR clusters. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/load-from-emr-steps-retrieve-key-and-ips.html